# How do I assign value to option in html.dropdownlist's list - razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

How do I assign value to option in `@Html.DropdownList`. I want to assign primary key (ID) to individual option in list and use jquery/ javaScript to read that selected value ID.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Group", new SelectList(Model.Groups.Select(g => g.GroupName)),
    "Select Group", new {id =item.UserID, @class = "GroupDropList" })
```

at the movement my output is as following;

```
<select class="GroupDropList" id="1" name="Group">
   <option value="">Select Group</option>
   <option>Group A</option>
   <option>Group B</option>
   <option>Group C</option>
   <option>new1</option>
</select>
```

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".GroupDropList").on('change', function () {
        var getValue = $(this).val();
        var SelectedItemID = $(this).attr("Id");
        alert(getValue+"  for "+SelectedItemID);
    });
});
```

### ViewModel (that I send to view via controller)

```
public class UserGroup_ViewModel
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can only add a `value` attribute (and `disabled` if using MVC-5) to an option tag using `@Html.DropDownList`

Comment: Does not matter, you cannot add an `id` attribute to options using `DropDownList()`. Why not create `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and set the `Value` property of `SelectListItem`?

Comment: `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is _the_  way to go.

Comment: Note also you cannot use the same name for the property you are binding to and the `SelectList` property. Change the `SelectList` property to (say) `GroupList`

Answer (score 2):

[SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx) has an overload where you can assign `dataValueField` and `dataTextField`:

```
new SelectList(Model.Groups, "GroupId", "GroupName")
```

Answer (score 2):

controller

```
 ViewBag.Group= new SelectList(Model.Groups, "GroupId", "GroupName");
```

Cshtml

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Group", null, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "$.GroupChange();", @class = "form-control"})
```

JQuery

```
$.GroupChange= function () {

    var GroupID= $("#Group").val();

    alert(GroupID);

}
```

Comment: `onchange=` Its the 21st century. Stop polluting your markup with behavior. Use best practice [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) as OP is doing